# How to open a link in Adobe Reader

Tags: browser, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

Certain PDF documents lose certain capabilities when opened on certain browsers. 
Suppose a document A.pdf  has links to B.pdf, and A.pdf is opened on some browser. Is there a way that the links in A.pdf are forced to open on Adobe Reader? (either coded into A.pdf or allowing user the choice of openning in in AR.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox and Chrome have their own built in PDF viewers. (Both also give the user the option to Download the PDF and open it using their default system PDF reader, usually Adobe.)

As far as I know their is no way to change which program opens a PDF from within the PDF itself.

However, you can force the user to download the PDF and open it in the system PDF reader using code or web server settings. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically for suggestions on how to do so.